# Indent text as desired

Tags: lists

I would like to indent the text as follows:[image: myfig.png]

I tried, but couldn't find  agood solution to this. Any help would be appreciable...

Comment: My impression is that this is the job for `description`.

Comment: If I type the text directly, they are getting intended completely (texts are also found under the 'Chap' also).

Comment: If you do not show any input we can not tell you what is wrong with the input but `\begin{description}\item[Chapter 2] introduces.....`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ..This is what, I was looking for.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `description` environment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Something to tell what this book is about. Now we
describe the contents of each chapter.

\begin{description}
\item[Chapter 2] deals with gnus, big animals rarely found in Arctic
regions, but that frequently plague silly text examples like this.
Note that gnus are not to be confused with gnats, that are much
smaller animals; enough of this silliness to fill up more than
two lines.

\item[Chapter 3] deals with reindeer, big animals that live in
cold countries and that are very important in this time of the year.
We'll tell how to possibly see reindeer, by remaining awake all the
night between 24 and 25 December.
\end{description}

Something more about the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to customize the description list; in this case the `enumitem` package is recommended. In the example, the indentation is set equal to the normal paragraph indentation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Something to tell what this book is about. Now we
describe the contents of each chapter.

\begin{description}[leftmargin=\parindent]
\item[Chapter 2] deals with gnus, big animals rarely found in Arctic
regions, but that frequently plague silly text examples like this.
Note that gnus are not to be confused with gnats, that are much
smaller animals; enough of this silliness to fill up more than
two lines.

\item[Chapter 3] deals with reindeer, big animals that live in
cold countries and that are very important in this time of the year.
We'll tell how to possibly see reindeer, by remaining awake all the 
night between 24 and 25 December.

\end{description}

Something more about the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg..I have already got the answer from "David"..Just for clarification. I couldn't find the difference between with and without 'enumitem' package

Comment: @user8162 Look closely at the amount of indentation in the two examples, in particular at the alignment of “reindeer” and ”Something” in the second one.